# How to modify GetAll function to apply pagination when get all data?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I working on `blazor` web application with .NET core 7 . I face Issue I can't implement Pagination when get all data from server Names model .

meaning I need to apply pagination when get all data with server side .

with code below I can get all data from server name joining with server type without any issue .

How to modify `GetAll function` to apply pagination when get all data?

what I try as below :

```
    public static class PagedResultExtensions
    {
        public static PagedResult<T> GetPaged<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int page, int pageSize) where T : class
        {
            var result = new PagedResult<T>();
            result.CurrentPage = page;
            result.PageSize = pageSize;
            result.RowCount = query.Count();

            var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
            result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

            var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
            result.Results = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
 public abstract class PagedResultBase
    {
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int PageCount { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int RowCount { get; set; }

        public int FirstRowOnPage
        {
            get { return (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize + 1; }
        }

        public int LastRowOnPage
        {
            get { return Math.Min(CurrentPage * PageSize, RowCount); }
        }
    }
public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase where T : class
        {
            public IList<T> Results { get; set; }
    
            public PagedResult()
            {
                Results = new List<T>();
            }
        }
```

Generic Base repository

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal AppsRepositoryDBContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(AppsRepositoryDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll() => _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
  
   
}
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

on service

```
 public class ServerNameService : BaseRepository<ServerNames>, IserverNamesService
    {
        private readonly AppsRepositoryDBContext _context;
        public ServerNameService(AppsRepositoryDBContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
 public IEnumerable<ServerNames> IserverNamesService.GetAll()
        {
            return _context.ServerNames
               .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
               sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
               st => st.ServerTypeId,
               (sn, st) => new ServerNames
               {
                   ServerID = sn.ServerID,
                   server_Name = sn.server_Name,
                   ServerType = st.ServerType
               }).ToList();
        }
      }
public interface IserverNamesService : IRepository<ServerNames>
    {
        IEnumerable<ServerNames> GetAll();
       
    }
```

on controller server names :

```
private readonly IserverNamesService _IserverNamesService;
        public  ServerNamesController(IserverNamesService IserverName)
        {
        _IserverNamesService = IserverName;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(_IserverNamesService.GetAll());
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any data request, making an unrestrained query i.e. `GetAll` is not a good idea. I know you see it all the time, the classic repository pattern does it. Consider the edge conditions: will your App gracefully handle a list of a million rows. Unlikely, but something goes wrong in an update process...?  If you don't code for edge conditions they will bite you!

First you need to define:

1. A request to pass into your data pipeline
2. A result that you get back.

If you don't want to page, set the PageSize in the request big enough to handle what you consider to be a maximum number of records.

Here's the request.

```cs
public sealed record ListQueryRequest
{
    public int StartIndex { get; init; } = 0;
    public int PageSize { get; init; } = 1000;  //set at some maximum epected count for no paging
    public CancellationToken Cancellation { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And the result.  Note it contains both the data and status information.

```cs
public sealed record ListQueryResult<TRecord>
{
    public IEnumerable<TRecord> Items { get; init;} = Enumerable.Empty<TRecord>();  
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public int TotalCount { get; init; }

    private ListQueryResult() { }

    public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Success(IEnumerable<TRecord> Items, int totalCount, string? message = null)
        => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> {Successful=true,  Items= Items, TotalCount = totalCount, Message= message ?? string.Empty };

    public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Failure(string message)
        => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> { Message = message};
}
```

You need to switch to using a DbContextFactory rather than a single reusable context.  See this MS Docs article on how to implement it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

Your repository pattern code then looks like this:

```cs
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
     private readonly IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> _factory;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async ValueTask<ListQueryResult<TEntity>> GetItemsAsync(ListQueryRequest)
    {
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();

        // switch off tracking for request only querying (no updates)
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        // Build your query before you actually execute/materialize it
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

        // Can do sorting or filtering here on the IQueryable 

        // Do a materialization to get the total count.
        var count = query.CountAsync(request.Cancellation);

        // apply paging to restrict the rows returned 
        query = query
            .Skip(request.StartIndex)
            .Take(request.PageSize);

        // Materialize the query into a list which you return as an IEnumerable
        var list await query.ToListAsync();

        // missing error checking code

        return ListQueryResult<TEntity>.Success(list, count);
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public ValueTask<ListQueryResult<TEntity>> GetItemsAsync(ListQueryRequest);
}
```

Your actual code will probably look like this (I don't know your model so there's a certain amount of guesswork)

```cs
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        IQueryable<TRecord> query = dbContext.ServerNames;
        query = query
            .Skip(request.StartIndex)
            .Take(request.PageSize);

        query = query
               .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
               sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
               st => st.ServerTypeId,
               (sn, st) => new ServerNames
               {
                   ServerID = sn.ServerID,
                   server_Name = sn.server_Name,
                   ServerType = st.ServerType
               });

        // Materialize the query into a list which you return as an IEnumerable
        // You need to do this before the DbContext goes out of scope
        var list await query.ToListAsync();
```

The final bit is how to handle this in a API call.  I use a Post, which breaks the traditionalists rule that Posts are for sending data updates.

My (generic) handler looks like this.  Note it uses an HttpClientFactory in a similar way to the DbContextFactory above.

```cs
public sealed class ListRequestAPIHandler
   : IListRequestHandler
{
   private IHttpClientFactory _factory;

   public ListRequestAPIHandler(IHttpClientFactory factory)
       => _factory = factory;

   public async ValueTask<ListQueryResult<TRecord>> ExecuteAsync<TRecord>(ListQueryRequest request)
       where TRecord : class, new()
   {
       ListQueryResult<TRecord>? result = null;

       var entityname = (new TRecord()).GetType().Name;

       var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient();
       var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ListQueryRequest>($"/api/{entityname}/listquery", request, request.Cancellation);

       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ListQueryResult<TRecord>>();

       return result ?? ListQueryResult<TRecord>.Failure($"{response.StatusCode} = {response.ReasonPhrase}"); ;
   }
}
```

And a generic Controller:

```cs
    [Route("/api/[controller]/listquery")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ListQueryResult<TRecord>> ListQuery([FromBody] ListQueryRequest query)
        => await _dataBroker.GetItemsAsync<TRecord>(query);
```